# Нужен совет от опытных, чайнику

Tags: php, html, css

Всем доброго времени суток.
Есть Div(1) С заданным размером 210Х297mm A4
Div(1) в цикле заполняется другими Div(2) с плавающим размером 80Х80, 60Х40, 80Х60мм и т.д.
Как сделать если div(2) не вмещаются по количеству,  создать 2-ой div(1) и перенести не вместившиеся div(2).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Суть программа печати этикеток.

```
<div(1)>
 <?php for ($i=0; $i < (количество постоянно меняется); $i++) {
  require "layout/div(2).php";
 } ?>
</div>
```

База заполняется данными => данные в цикле заполняют этикетки (попутно заполняя форму для печати).

Все работает, проблема именно в выводе на печать.
Заранее прощу не кидать тапками. Я только учусь.

Comment: я бы попробовал реализовать это средствами js, алгоритм получается следующий, 1. рендерим в цикле этикетки, для каждой срендереной этикетки проверяем наличие свободного места в контейнере(div), если есть добавляем в контейнер иначе создаем новый контейнер в который будем вставлять последующие этикетки. для выполнения этого алгоритма надо знать два значение размер этикетки, и оставшееся место в контейнере, может быть вы сможете реализовать описанный алгоритм средствами php

Comment: приведите пример кода, то что на выходе страницы.

Comment: Спасибо попробую разобраться. В js пока только начал разбираться.

Comment: Покажите реальный код цикла. Покажите код файла, который реквайрите. Что бы это проблему решить средствами php, необходимо менять логику ещё до форича. Если пытаться решать по тому, как сейчас всё организованно - получите кучу костылей и не факт, что работающих как надо.

Answer (score 0):

можете попробовать решить как то так:

```
<?
    $amount = "Количество";
    $blocksAmount = ceil($amount / 4);

    for ($j = 0; $j < $blocksAmount; $j++) {
?>
<div>
<?
        for ($i = $j * 4;  $i < ($j * 4) + 4; $i++) {
            require "layout/div(2).php";
        }
?>
</div>
<?
    }
?>
```

Comment: так размеры этикеток вроде как плавающие...

Comment: Хмм, не заметил, в таком случае, если методами php вы можете определить размер каждой этикетки, то можете немного переделать мой пример, то есть перед выводом все в очередной div проверять заполненность(можете создать какую либо шкалу) и в зависимости от этого условия либо выводить этот элемент в этом же контейнере, либо создавать новый

Comment: Попробовал немного не подходит. Сохраню на будущее пример. Спасибо.